# Fallback option for older browsers expand to available height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know I can use flexbox fit all children to the biggest height but I would like a fall back option for IE10 and friends:

I thought I could use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` but it does not appear to like fixed heights and I think `table-layout: fixed` only works by sizing to the first cell's height if it is the biggest.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.gel-layout {
  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.gel-layout--equal {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.gel-1\/3 {
  width: 33.33333333%!important;
}

.gel-layout__item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gel-layout--equal>.gel-layout__item {
  display: table-cell;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #d4e7eb;
  color: #121212;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto {
  height: auto;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #d4e7eb, #d4e7eb 8px, #aec4cc 0, #aec4cc 16px);
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--first {
  height: 72px;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--large {
  height: 144px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <h2>Equal Height</h2>
    <div class="gel-layout gel-layout--equal">
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3 left">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--first">one</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--large gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">three</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's why flexbox & CSS-Grid were developed...the fallback is JS,

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the height and added `height:1px` which acts as a hack to set the height children to the max and added `display:inline-table;` for inner children to fix the issue on firefox pointed by @Stickers

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.gel-layout {
  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.gel-layout--equal {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:1px; /* a hack to set the height of the children equal */
}

.gel-1\/3 {
  width: 33.33333333%!important;
}

.gel-layout__item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gel-layout--equal>.gel-layout__item {
  display: table-cell;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #d4e7eb;
  color: #121212;
  height: 100%; /* added this height to make the height equal to the greatest element */
  display:inline-table; /* to fix firefox issue */
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto {
  /*height: auto; commented this height */
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #d4e7eb, #d4e7eb 8px, #aec4cc 0, #aec4cc 16px);
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--first {
  /*height: 72px; commented this height*/
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--large {
  height: 144px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>
      <h2>Equal Height</h2>
      <div class="gel-layout gel-layout--equal">
        <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3 left">
          <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--first">one</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
          <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
          <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--large gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

another version with large content

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.gel-layout {
  list-style: none;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.gel-layout--equal {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:1px; /* a hack to set the height of the children equal */
}

.gel-1\/3 {
  width: 33.33333333%!important;
}

.gel-layout__item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gel-layout--equal>.gel-layout__item {
  display: table-cell;
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #d4e7eb;
  color: #121212;
  height: 100%; /* added this height to make the height equal to the greatest element */
  display:inline-table;/* to fix firefox issue */
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto {
  /*height: auto; commented this height */
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #d4e7eb, #d4e7eb 8px, #aec4cc 0, #aec4cc 16px);
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--first {
  /*height: 72px; commented this height*/
}

.gel-c-grid-demo-item--large {
  /*height: 144px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <h2>Equal Height</h2>
    <div class="gel-layout gel-layout--equal">
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3 left">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--auto gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--first">one</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gel-layout__item gel-1/3">
        <div class="gel-c-grid-demo-item gel-c-grid-demo-item--large gel-c-grid-demo-item--fill">three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>three
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try it on Firefox.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes I am very sorry to say your excellent effort does not work in IE10.  I'm very curious to know why the height: 1px hack works

Answer (score 0):

- Removed the div `.item` and condense all classes. `display:table` or `display:table-row` must be the parent (direct ancestor) of the `display:table-cell` so that normal table behavior (like equal heights) can work.
- Applied `border-spacing` to `display:table`. Tables components ignore margins so border-spacing was necessary to separate and define each box as a separate cell.
- Removed the `.gel-1\/3` although valid was scary and ineffectual since the `display:table-cell` under `display:table`/`table-layout`/`width:100%` already makes the cells 33.33%.
- When condensing all of the classes, I wanted to make sure there were no classes with double hyphens `--` because they are used by CSS variable but they are valid, just not entirely safe.

#### Demo

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #d4e7eb;
  color: #121212;
  /*outline:2px solid red;*/
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, #d4e7eb, #d4e7eb 8px, #aec4cc 0, #aec4cc 16px);
}

.first {
  height: 72px;
}

.large {
  height: 144px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>

</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
  
        <h2>Equal Height</h2>
        <div class="table">

            <div class="cell first">one</div>

            <div class="cell">two</div>

            <div class="cell large">three</div>
 
        </div>
      </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```